# Bootstrap popup not appear on click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am making signup/login popup in menu and loading content through file. MY problem is when I try to access popup content from other file popup is not appear.(in other words access content through remotely)

Here is my code

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <li><i class="fa fa-users"></i><a href="register.html" id="signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signup-modal">Sign Up</a></li>

On other file code where popup content is add
<div class="modal fade" id="signup-modal">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header signup_modal_header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Registration Form</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body signup-modal">content</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/vtd72x4o/)**

Comment: Because this is on one page. If I have added popup code in other file the popup is not appear.

Comment: You have to mention the correct scenario buddy!! But however the scenario may be if render happens properly and if the `modal` appears to be there in DOM then this should definitely work!!

Comment: for me not working if I tried access whole popup content remotely.